# PHP/JavaBridge on Tomcat Bitnami AWS

Tags: php, tomcat, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, bitnami

I need to configure PHP JavaBridge on Bitnami Tomcat stack on Amazon EC2.

I launched my BitnamiTomcat instance on AWS EC2.

Then I deployed in webapps the /opt/bitnami/apache-tomcat/webapps the JavaBridge.war

Then, following instructions at https://wiki.bitnami.com/Components/PHP-FPM I enabled FPM on PHP: infact now if I check php configuration with phpinfo() command I get

```
Server API  FPM/FastCGI
```

So I think it is correctly configured.
But if I browse to http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/JavaBridge/ I'm getting this error

```
type Exception report

message php.java.bridge.http.FCGIConnectException: Could not connect to server

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: php.java.bridge.http.FCGIConnectException: Could not connect to server
    php.java.servlet.fastcgi.FastCGIServlet.init(FastCGIServlet.java:133)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436)
    org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProcessor.process(AjpAprProcessor.java:188)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2517)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2506)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
.....
.....
```

So I'm not sure that JavaPHPBridge is compatible with FPM/FastCGI or what I missed something in my procedure

Please is there anyone who can help me, because I searched on Google a lot to find something about configuration of PHP-FPM and PHP/JavaBridge but was not able to get nothing usefull and clear.

Kind regards,
Matt